# how to fetch data from promise object which is in json format

Tags: javascript, promise, google-api

I'm trying to calculate distance from google api using fetch now i convert data into json which is in promise object and json fromat here is my code and also the screenshot of what I'm getting now

i try so far but getting undefined error every time.

```
fetch(proxyurl + re)
            .then(function(response) {

                console.log (response.json());
            });
```

i want to get data of source and destination time and distance

here is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz51R.png

Comment: get this error please see search:4767 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: `response.json().rows[0][0].distance` is the first distance value returned

Comment: Thanks sir but i did the same and get the error did you see the attached screenshot  
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz51R.png

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks like you should have accessed`.rows[0].elements[0].distance`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your fetch method like this:

```
fetch('https://api-endpoint.com')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
       console.log(data);
    });
```

Demo with github users endpoint: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-bush-wqn70

Comment: still got the same error "(in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" i also attached the screenshot in my question please have a look.

Comment: Thanks you so much got the value.